# Codeigniter Controller return to previous page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'd like to ask you how can I instead of $this->load->view('some_view.php') at the end of controller code, return user to page from where he invoked controller method? Simple return statement is not working.

ie.

```
public function someMethod($IDCustomer) {

     $this->Some_modal->persist($IDCustomer);   
     // how to return to previous page instead of line after?
     // i've used $this->load->view('someView.php');
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This should help http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/user_agent.html

```
$this->load->library('user_agent');
if ($this->agent->is_referral())
{
    echo $this->agent->referrer();
}
```

or straight PHP:

```
redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Comment: Is there any way to be redirected to refreshed previous page? Or to refresh previous page simply?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean.

Comment: I've tried this solution, but i don't get thing that I've expected. Let's try to make this clear, I've got table with songs (first column i got buy button which my view generated based on fact if I've not already bought it, if i have bought it i would put instead of "cart icon = buy button" something to inform that song is already bought. When i invoke controller method and when i go back my view isn't generated again (i won't see change on song that I've already bought unless I refresh page).

Comment: redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); works for me. thanks!

Answer (score 16):

I've found answer on some thread.

> In the page that you want to go back to you can do:
>
> `$this->session->set_userdata('referred_from', current_url());`
>
> Then redirect back to that page
>
> ```
> $referred_from = $this->session->userdata('referred_from');
> redirect($referred_from, 'refresh');
> ```

Answer (score 2):

In Codeigniter 4 You can use `previous_url()` function from url helper

find more https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Answer (score 1):

Tried `return redirect()->to($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);` , this would work well.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried `header('location:'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);` and it's working quite well.

Just a one-liner plain old PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING` alternative of `HTTP_REFERRER`:

```
// set in session redirect back URL in your common is_logged_in function if user is not logged in

$CI->session->set_userdata('redirect_back', $_SERVER['REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING']); 


// below code user after successful login in auth.php library

if($this->ci->session->userdata('redirect_back')){
    $redirectBackUrl = $this->ci->session->userdata('redirect_back');
    $this->ci->session->unset_userdata('redirect_back');
    redirect(base_url() . $redirectBackUrl);
}
```